# Panels block title translation

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n, panels

I use blocks in a panel with Drupal 8. With view generated blocks there are no problems: The block titles are translated accordingly to the view settings. With custom blocks, it appears to be problematic to get the block title translated. I hoped that these titles would be translatable via the user interface translation but they are not; plus, in the panel settings, I can set the block title, but I cannot translate it.

How can I translate block titles (and maybe block content) of custom blocks in a panel, with Drupal 8?

Answer (score -1):

You can override the block.html.twig template and handle the translation of the title directly on the template:

```
    {{ label|t }}
```

You may need to confirm the title structure (if is #markup or plain text/string)

Answer (score -1):

Page variants are translatable using config translation at /admin/config/regional/config-translation